# Can't redirect to https (htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I was trying to configure my htaccess file which will redirect from http to https with following lines of statement. But it couldn't .

Note: i don't want the www before the site URL as well.

What could be possible error of my code. Anyone please suggest.

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem appears to be this line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
```

This line makes this rule work for domain with starting `www` only.

You need to make starting `www` optional by using:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 1):

As another solution, if you have only one domain name `(www.)example.com`, you can use more readable:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```html
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Also, you can also redirect based on port number, for example:

```html
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
 RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect all requests received on port 80 to HTTPS.